# Should I use a Transaction or Roll-Your-Own locking to prevent records from being processed multiple times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a process that runs once every 20 minutes to process records in a certain status.

This works fine, until there are so many records that the process has not yet finished and it starts again.  Thus the same records are processed a second time.

This code was written without the use of Transactions.

I can see two ways to resolve:

1. Put Code in a Transaction so that when the process runs a second time, those records are locked.
2. Create a controller table and set a flag when the process starts, and then unset the flag when the process completes.

I have no real world experience with this, and am not sure if one is more beneficial than the other.

To me, I would say using a Transaction would be the foolproof way to go, as there is no way for that to go wrong.  Setting a Flag could be problematic, as if the flag was never unset, then the process would not run again.

I don't see a negative aspect to using the Transaction, other than locking those records for an extended period of time.

Comment: I would put some logic on your process instead. Trying to roll your own locking is going to end up a huge challenge. This question is really going to boil down to opinion but preventing the process is a far better and simpler approach imho. If you lock every row you need to edit and your process crashes you can have a real mess on your hands.

Comment: I don't understand: If I lock the records with a Transaction, and the process crashes, wouldn't SQL Server roll back the Transaction Automatically?

Comment: But I agree with your comment that putting login in the process is a great idea so it doesn't run twice.

Comment: Yes it would. I thought you were talking about rolling your own locking mechanism.

Comment: Not unless you tell sql server to do so.

Comment: And if you really need to be sure it doesn't get stuck not running add some additional logic that if the process is locked and it has been locked for more than 30 minutes (or whatever), it could send an email to an admin that there is a problem.

Comment: @SeanLange If you post your comment as answer, I will accept.

Comment: Generally two long transactions processing the same set of rows possess higher risk of  deadlock. I'd prefer to serialize them.

Comment: @Serg I am not sure what you mean - how would you serialize them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put some logic on your process instead. Trying to roll your own locking is going to end up a huge challenge. This question is really going to boil down to opinion but preventing the process is a far better and simpler approach imho. If you lock every row you need to edit and your process crashes you can have a real mess on your hands. And if you really need to be sure it doesn't get stuck not running add some additional logic that if the process is locked and it has been locked for more than 30 minutes (or whatever), it could send an email to an admin that there is a problem.

The idea here is to prevent your process from running more than 1 instance at a time. I would still recommend putting your DML inside a transaction in your process.

Comment: Ahh.  The C# word for this is: Mutex (Mutual Exclusive Object).

Answer (score 0):

Whatever process you use, it needs some sort of logging and a processing logic. It should be able to tell if the previous run was successful, failed or it's still running. If it runs every 20 minutes, wait for the next trigger when a process is still executing. Alternatively you could use delta loading without exclusive locks, you would check if the rows you try to insert don't already exist or changed.